# Django Please help me place a checkbox and a mail box with a send button on the html page

Tags: python, django, checkbox, subscribe

One of functionality in my training project:

1. subscribe to the news by check-box and e-mail.
2. Send newsletter daily.
3. The user can unsubscribe from the mailing list in his profile by unchecking the checkbox.

It so happened that first I set up a daily newsletter for users who have booleanfield = true.
For it I marked the checkboxes in the admin panel. It works.
Now it is necessary to add the checkbox and the mail field to the news page.
I'm stuck on the simplest. Tired and confused.
Please help me place a checkbox and a mail box with a send button on the news page

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
hr = models.BooleanField(default=False)
subscribed_for_mailings = models.BooleanField(default=False)
subscription_email = models.EmailField(default="")

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class MailingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile
        fields = ('subscription_email', 'subscribed_for_mailings', )
        widgets = {
            'subscription_email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Your Email..."}),
            'subscribed_for_mailings': forms.CheckboxInput,
        }
```

**views.py**

```
    def all_news(request):
    today = date.today()
    today_news = models.TopNews.objects.filter(created__gte=today)
    return render(request, "news.html",
                  {'today_news': today_news})


def mailing_news(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mailing_form = forms.MailingForm(request.POST)
        if mailing_form.is_valid():
            mailing_form.save()
            return HttpResponse('You will receive news by mail')
    else:
        mailing_form = forms.MailingForm()
        return render(request, "news.html", {'mailing_form': mailing_form})
```

**urls.py**

```
...
path('news/', views.all_news, name='all_news'),
...
```

**news.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    News
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Last news</h1>
    {% for news in today_news%}
        <h3>{{ news.title }}</h3>
        <a href="{{ news.link }}">Read this news</a>
        <p>
              {{ news.created }}
        </p>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}

<h4>I want to receive news by mail</h4>
        <form action="." method="post">
            {{ mailing_form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label>
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
            </label>
        </form>

{% endblock %}
```

The page displays a list of news and only the "send" button. There is no check-box and a field for mail
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZO0F.jpg)

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: You should include some kind of a traceback or explain the error you got and what you intend to do

Comment: The page displays a list of news and only the "send" button. There is no check-box and a field for mail

Comment: Try to change `mailing_form = forms.MailingForm(request.POST)` to `mailing_form = forms.MailingForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)` and `mailing_form = forms.MailingForm()` to mailing_form = forms.MailingForm(instance=request.user.profile)`. That's all I see wrong with your code. Maybe there's something else I don't see

Comment: @EnePaul, it's not helped ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I realized this functionality in a different way:

**forms.py**

```
class MailingForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = models.Profile
    fields = ('subscribed_for_mailings', 'subscription_email', )
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def mailing_news(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        mailing_form = forms.MailingForm(request.POST,
                                             instance=request.user.profile,
                                             )
        if mailing_form.is_valid():
            mailing_news = mailing_form.save(commit=False)
            mailing_news.subscribed_for_mailings = mailing_news.subscribed_for_mailings
            mailing_news.subscription_email = mailing_news.subscription_email
            mailing_news.save()

            return render(request, "subscribe_complete.html",
                          {"mailing_news": mailing_news})
    else:
        mailing_form = forms.MailingForm()
    return render(request, 'subscribe.html', {"mailing_form": mailing_form})
```

**news.html**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    News
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <h1>Last news</h1> {{ news.created }}
    {% for news in today_news%}
        <h3>{{ news.title }}</h3>
        <a href="{{ news.link }}">Read this news</a>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}

<a href="{% url 'basis:subscribe' %}">I want to receive news by mail</a>

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
...
path('subscribe/', views.mailing_news, name='subscribe')
...
```

**news.html**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    News
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <h1>Last news</h1> {{ news.created }}
    {% for news in today_news%}
        <h3>{{ news.title }}</h3>
        <a href="{{ news.link }}">Read this news</a>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}

<a href="{% url 'basis:subscribe' %}">I want to receive news by mail</a>

{% endblock %}
```

**subscribe.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Subscribe
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
        <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ mailing_news.as_p }}
                {% if user.profile.subscribed_for_mailings is True %}
                    <input type="checkbox" name="subscribed_for_mailings" id="id_subscribed_for_mailings" checked="">
                    If you don't want to receive emails anymore, uncheck
                    <br>
                    Subscription email: <input type="email" name="subscription_email" value={{ user.profile.subscription_email }} class="vTextField" maxlength="254" id="id_subscription_email">
                {% else %}
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="subscribed_for_mailings" id="id_subscribed_for_mailings">
                        I want to subscribe for mailing news
                    </label>
                    <p><label>
                        Send news on my email:
                        <input type="email" name="subscription_email" class="vTextField" maxlength="254" id="id_subscription_email">
                    </label></p>

                {% endif %}
            <p><input type="submit" value="Update"></p>
        </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**subscribe_complete.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Subscribing complete
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h3>Hi {{ user.username }}</h3>

    Thanks for subscribing.
    You will receive daily news by email: {{ user.profile.subscription_email }}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to change `subscribed_for_mailings` in `mailing news`, like this

```
def mailing_news(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    mailing_form = forms.MailingForm(request.POST)
    if mailing_form.is_valid():
        profile = mailing_form.save(commit=False) ####
        profile.subscribed_for_mailings = mailing_form.cleaned_data.get('subscribed_for_mailings') ####
        profile.subscription_email = mailing_form.cleaned_data.get('subscription_email') ####
        profile.save() #### new_line

        return HttpResponse('You will receive news by mail')
else:
    mailing_form = forms.MailingForm()
    return render(request, "news.html", {'mailing_form': mailing_form})
```

you can change in `cleaned_data.get('....')`

Comment: I think the profile was already created in this case. You need to edit the existing one, not create another. And where do you get the user from. The Profile object needs a user. This answer is wrong.